# What API can I use to see my GCP bill amount?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I would like to see my current bill on my GCP project. I tried using the Billing API and the Budget API but they just give me meta data information. No bill with costs on it. I would like to know the current bill **cost** for the month.

I know there is a Pub/Sub way to do this, but I don't want to get notified of the billing cost. I would like to see the bill cost when on demand.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/budget/rest/v1/billingAccounts.budgets/get)?

Comment: Yes. In [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/budget/rest/v1/billingAccounts.budgets#Budget), it shows the response. It's just metadata information. No cost.

Comment: `"amount"` field has object `BudgetAmount` which has object `Money`, this object holds the amount. Refer this [link](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/budget/rest/Shared.Types/Money). Did you check it out?

Comment: Yes. But isn't this the **budget** amount. Not the **billing** amount? For example, I just went into my GCP and set the budget to $13.37. Now it displays that budget I put. But I don't want the budget. I want to know my bill cost. Here is the API response I just tested: https://imgur.com/e6dSKGL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this moment as per the [list](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/) of [available](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rpc/) 'Cloud billing APIs', GCP don't have such an API to view usage/total cost of a project. Here is the [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/124508767) for this.

As per the [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/150209085) there is no such API that would provide real-time billing cost and this is Feature Request as billing Engineering team working on this.

Comment: Is it still pending?