# API for getting daily costs related to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-client-login

Is there any API(preferably python) that can be used to get the resources' usage cost report in GCP? Billing APIs don't seem to return the costs of resources being used.

Comment: Please look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/66081777/11866104

Comment: You can use BigQuery export and then query BigQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You can export you cloud billing data to BigQuery:
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-setup

You select the dataset where the cost metadata goes, once in BigQuery, it's fairly easy to query, which you can do with the python BigQuery client API, it also makes sure you keep a historic in case you change billing provider, of course it'll incur storage cost which will vary based on your usage.